# Target image map to move on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

i want to animate  different parts of image on `mousemove event` . I've divided image in 4 parts like this

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="58,158,304,188,224,268" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="714,62,724,59,721,74,715,178,696,168,676,155,652,150,635,150,762,36" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="264,352,185,478,444,356,294,378" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="720,209,867,243,418,133,458,162,455,167" />
    [...]
</map>
```

these parts are clickable but how do i target them separately and move animate them i  need help with this

Comment: Image maps are not visible, then what kind of animation do you want to see?

Comment: my image is like a start i want to animate corners on hover , i divided 4 corners like above thats the only way i could thought of doing it